# re.split() with special cases

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regular expression and have a problem with the re.split functionality.

In my case the split has to care "special escapes".

The text should be seperated at `;`, except there is a leading `?`.

**Edit:** In that case the two parts shouldn't be splitted and the `?` has to be removed.

Here an example and the result I wish:

```
import re
txt = 'abc;vwx?;yz;123'
re.split(r'magical pattern', txt)
['abc', 'vwx;yz', '123']
```

I tried so far these attempt:

```
re.split(r'(?<!\?);', txt)
```

and got:

```
['abc', 'vwx?;yz', '123']
```

Sadly causes the not consumed `?` trouble and the following list comprehension is to performance critical:

```
[part.replace('?;', ';') for part in re.split(r'(?<!\?);', txt)]
['abc', 'vwx;yz', '123']
```

Is there a "fast" way to reproduce that behavior with re?

Could the re.findall function be the solution to take?

For example a extended version of this code:

```
re.findall(r'[^;]+', txt)
```

I am using python 2.7.3.

Thanking you in anticipation!

Comment: So what you want is *two* things: To split on `;`, and to *remove* the `?` escape character from `?;` after splitting, correct?

Comment: Because that is two separate tasks, your approach was correct already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with one regular expression. Unescaping `?;` after splitting is a separate task altogether, not one that you can get the `re` module to do for you while splitting at the same time.

Just keep the task separate; you could use a generator to do the unescaping for you:

```
def unescape(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield item.replace('?;', ';')

for elem in unescape(re.split(r'(?<!\?);', txt)):
    print elem
```

but that won't be faster than your list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answers and workaround ideas. I'll accept this answer, because it seems to be true that there is no way to achieve this task with only one regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

Regex is not the tool for the job. Use the `csv` module instead:

```
>>> txt = 'abc;vwx?;yz;123'
>>> r = csv.reader([txt], delimiter=';', escapechar='?')
>>> next(r)
['abc', 'vwx;yz', '123']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
 re.sub('(?<!\?);',r'|', txt).replace('?;',';').split('|')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-)

```
def split( txt, sep, esc, escape_chars):
    ''' Split a string
        txt - string to split
        sep - separator, one character
        esc - escape character
        escape_chars - List of characters allowed to be escaped
    '''
    l = []
    tmp = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(txt):
        if len(txt) > i + 1 and txt[i] == esc and txt[i+1] in escape_chars:
            i += 1
            tmp.append(txt[i])
        elif txt[i] == sep:
            l.append("".join(tmp))
            tmp = []
        elif txt[i] == esc:
            print('Escape Error')
        else:
            tmp.append(txt[i])
        i += 1
    l.append("".join(tmp))
    return l

if __name__ == "__main__":
    txt = 'abc;vwx?;yz;123'
    print split(txt, ';', '?', [';','\\','?'])
```

Returns:

```
['abc', 'vwx;yz', '123']
```